# Pyrhon and Django AttributeError ".save"

Tags: python, django, django-models, attributeerror

The propelem is I'm getting an error at this line:

```
      s_lance.seve()
```

It's an Attribute error
Views.py

```
  def f(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        titulo = request.POST['titulo']
        user = request.user 
        descricao = request.POST['descricao']
      
        s_lance = Produto(titulo = titulo, user = user, descricao = descricao)
        s_lance.seve()
```

models.py

```
class Produto(models.Model):
        titulo = models.CharField(max_length=25)
        descricao = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="lista", default=None)
```

I expected that  values would be saved.  However, I got this AttributeError [image: Atrributeerror]

Comment: It is `save()`, not `seve()`.

Answer (score 1):

it's `.save()`

And you can also use: 
`s_lance = Produto.objects.create(titulo=titulo, user=user, descricao=descricao)`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.create